# How to link a font folder from FontAwesome

Tags: html, css, frontend, font-awesome

Hello I am trying to add the fonts from FontAwesome in order to use their icons and they require a root folder called Fonts.

I have tried to link it with

```
<link type="text/css" href="/myPath/font" />
```

Comment: You need to add the reference to the `.css` file. Something like: `href="/myPath/font-awesome.css"` or try to use a cdn: `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css`

Comment: I cannot use a cdn it has to be offline. also the font folder has eot and svg files

Comment: Should there also a `.css` file.

Comment: yes i have the css file already and that works i just cannot get the icons

Comment: Any errors in the console? See if the element with the class `fa` have some styles (in devtools)..

Comment: no errors in console i found this link: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/

Comment: The `.css` should take care about everything for you.. You don't need to define the fontface.. You need to check if you do everything OK. Like add the right classes to the elements and your files are in the right hierarchy, and you have right references in your html and css files.

Comment: @Ninowis is onto something. Basically my font folder is hidden and i need someway to tell my html or css where it is.

Comment: What do you mean by `hidden`? hidden folder in windows for example? I don't think that it change anything. As long as the folder exist, it should work. Are you using less or sass?

Comment: well its at a secure server so there is a specific directory for which the file has to go to.

Comment: this seems to be heading towards a backend permissions, "My app can't see my files," issue more than an issue specifically related to font-awesome

Answer (score 2):

The fonts from FontAwesome are declared in an @font-face rule in the css.
If you use the less or scss version, you can just override the path set in variables:

```
$fa-font-path:        "path/to/your/fonts";
```

If you just use the css version, you should be able to redeclare the font-face rule (replace '../fonts/' by your path):

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.6.3');
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.6.3') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.6.3') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.6.3') format('woff'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.6.3') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.6.3#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: are the "?" necessary in the url?

Comment: No they're not, it's a good practice to force the cache to reload the files should you update to a newer version of the files (with the same file name)

Comment: I mean the "?v=4.6.3" don't just remove the "?" ;-)

Comment: Happy to help. Please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted, it might help others ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Just curious, how exactly do you know the fonts are not being pulled in?  Is it because you are unable to create icons using font-awesome?

Aside from that, if you installed font-awesome with bower, npm or pulled from github it should have the following directory structure.

```
font-awesome
    css
        font-awesome.css
    font
        (font files / eot, svg, ttf, woff)
```

If it is in this directory structure then your css should point to those font files.  Then it's just a matter of pulling in the font-awesome css like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{path}}/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" />
```

I would double check your directory structure for font-awesome and maybe try installing it via bower if nothing else.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i am aware you have to add the link to the **css** file and the **css** file will link to the font folder which is preset by the font-awesome library. Therefore your code will contain the **font-awesome.min.css** file and you will need to have the font folder in the same directory,but the link will look in the html like this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font-awesome.min.css"/>
```

or using the cdn:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

use chrome browser,

Press F12 when and goto console tab

check details of errors and it will show the path browser is looking for FONTS,

just make sure that fonts are present on that path...

that's it...